# Rename files & folders recursively in Windows (7) to [A-Za-z0-9-]

Tags: windows, file-rename

I search a solution to rename files and folders recursively in Windows (7) to [A-Za-z0-9-].

I will post a question, but this is not perfect and without folder rename. I search also for a better solution. A batch file is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not realy perfect. Also search for a better solution.

I have do it with FreeCommander XE:

This tutorial works only recursively for files. With folder, this have a problem with recursively, because subfolder with already renamed parent folder are not renamed.

Hint: Please be absolutely carefull. You can rename all filenames irreversible!
When you have the capacity, make it with a copy. That is not a joke.

```
Open the Folder in a tab.
Check, that the tab with the folder is active (bold path name).
Click the "Search" icon.
It opens a new window.
File name: *
Click "Find".
Mark all Files.
Menue: File → Export to file container → Export selected items
It opens all the files in a temporary folder in a new tab in the main window.
In this (C:TmpFileContainer-1.fcc) please mark only all files.
Menue: File → Multirename
It opens a new window.
```

Special (two bit) chars INFO:
search = aequivalent → alternative

```
[i don't know] = Ä → Ae
+ñ = ä → ae
+û = Ö → Oe
+Â = ö → oe
+£ = Ü → Ue
++ = ü → ue
[i don't know] = ẞ → SS
+ƒ = ß → ss
```

[i don't know] = you know it? please write it in a comment. [Question: What is the name of this References?]

In the Multirename window:
First: search & replace the special (two bit) chars, because, this have not special chars included (see below at regular expression).

```
Select "Replace all occurence".
Select "Exlcude extension".

And Select "Auto Preview" and check the result befor click the "Rename" button.
After the rename click "Reload".
Please be absolutely carefull!
```

search → replace

```
+ñ → ae
+û → Oe
+Â → oe
+£ → Ue
++ → ue
+ƒ → ss
```

Make a new search:

```
search for: +
```

(you find eventually an another special char / two bit char)

Do the same with these as with the others.

Search an replace for HTML URL Encoding Reference:

List of entities and characters: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

In most cases not all references are present in the filenames.

Yet search & replace with Regular expression.
Please be absolutely carefull!

```
Select "Replace all occurence".
Select "Exlcude extension".
Select "Regular expression".
```

search → replace:

```
\W → -
```

Info: The capital W match all chars, except a-zA-Z0-9. But a-zA-Z0-9 included unfortunately ñ û Â and similar and except it. Therefore first rename the special (two bit) chars.

Or use an another pattern like this:

```
_|&|\.|\s|\+|\(|\)|=
```

Further replaces (Umlaute):

```
Select "case sensitive".
Select "Replace all occurence".
```

search → replace

```
Ä → Ae
Ö → Oe
Ü → Ue
ä → ae
ö → oe
ü → ue
ß → ss
```

Last but not least:
search → replace:

```
Select "Replace all occurence".

_ → -
```

Special search → replace:
Leading dashes:

```
^- →
```

(rename to nothing)
Trailing dashes:

```
-$ →
```

(rename to nothing)

Don't forget to check the renamed filenames every time befor click the "Rename" button.